# Регистрация пользователя в телеграм боте. Какой подход лучше выбрать?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, шаблоны-проектирования, регистрация

Мой вопрос скорее не про "как сделать", а про "как сделать правильно". Я создаю телеграм бота и мне нужно зарегистрировать пользователя. Регистрация проходит по следующему принципу: `пользователь нажимает кнопку /start` -> `в базу заносится новый пользователь, некоторые поля пустые`. Дальше пользователь несколько раз вводит информацию о себе и пустые поля постепенно заполняются (знаю, что лучше собрать всю информацию и только потом отправлять её в бд, но не совсем понимаю, как это сделать).

Текущая реализация примерно такая: есть класс `CommandExecutor` - некое подобие стейт-машины, так же есть класс `StartCommand`, в котором пока что реализован только первый этап регистрации.

Итак, вопрос: как быть дальше? Как мне отслеживать, в каком состоянии заполнения профиля сейчас находится пользователь? Сделать очередную стейт-машину в `StartCommand`? Но тогда получится стейт-машина внутри другой стейт-машины... Звучит не очень. Другой вариант - сделать несколько классов, каждый из которых будет отвечать за свой этап регистрации, и вызывать их исполняющие методы из `CommandExecutor`. Но это тоже как будто не совсем верно, ведь процесс регистрации распадается на много отдельных сущностей. Скорее всего, есть какой-то другой, более простой, способ, о котором я не знаю. Прошу мне на него указать.

условная реализация `CommandExecuor`:

```
private ICommand? currentCommand;

public async Task Execute(Update update)
    {
        currentCommand = new StartCommand()

        if (currentCommand != null)
        {
            await currentCommand.Execute(update);
        }
            
    }
```

P.S. Я только закончил 11 класс, знаний у меня нет, а опыта - тем более) Поэтому, если посоветуете статью/книгу по asp.net, веб-разработке, паттернах, буду безмерно благодарен.

Comment: Не технический вопрос, но… Сразу после `/start` добавлять мовитон! Спроси у пользователя, хочет ли он зарегистрироваться, а там уже начинай регистрацию если "*да*". Состояние можно поддерживать на уровне сессии, что логично. Если полностью на все вопросы не ответит, можно будет напомнить об этом по timeout.

Comment: а почему вы выбрали именно c# для выполнения этой задачи?

Comment: @1001001, просто мне нравится C# и его я знаю лучше, чем другие яп. Так же потому что хочется попрактиковаться в написании asp.net приложений. А это имеет какое-то значение?

Comment: @LightChimera спросил для себя. интереса ради)

Comment: Для меня этот вопрос так же является актуальным, занимаюсь разработкой диалогового чат бота на c#.
Пожалуйста, если у вас появился ответ - расскажите о нём здесь

Comment: @ВикторДробышев, к сожалению так и не нашел удовлетворительного решения, по итогу свёл все к тому, что регистрация происходит за один этап, одним сообщением.